# Let $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be compact and $f\colon X \to \mathbb R$ be continuous, then...

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be compact and $f\colon X \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Prove that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \text{  }\exists M \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t.} \text{ } \forall x,y \in X $ we have $|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant M|x-y| + \epsilon$

So I'm trying with proof by contradiction:  $$\exists \epsilon_0 > 0 \text{ }\forall M \in\mathbb R \text{ } \exists a_M,b_M \in X \text{ with } M|a_M - b_M| + \epsilon_0 < |f(a_M) - f(b_M)|$$

(I write $a_M$ and $b_M$ to emphasize that they depend on $M$ )

I have been able to deduce that if $M \geq 0$ then $|f(a_M) - f(b_M)| >\epsilon_0$. because we have $$M|a_M - b_M| + \epsilon_0 < |f(a_M) - f(b_M)| $$ so  $$|a_M - b_M| < \frac{|f(a_M) - f(b_M)| - \epsilon_0}{M}$$ since $|a_M - b_M| \geqslant 0$ the right hand side $\frac{|f(a_M) - f(b_M)| - \epsilon_0}{M} > 0 $ and the inequality follows (assuming that $M \neq 0$, if $M = 0$,  we obtain the inequality immediately).

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, I know there exists a $\delta_0 > 0$ such that if any two points are within $\delta_0$, then their images are within $\epsilon_0$. So if I can prove that $|a_M - b_M| < \delta_0$, I would get a contradiction but I haven't been able to prove it. So that's where I'm stuck.

Could someone please provide a hint? I don't want the solution, just a hint :D

Comment: Note, $f$ is uniformly continuous.Then, what can you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the contrary that for some $\epsilon>0$, there are $x_{n},y_{n}\in X$ such that $|f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})|>n|x_{n}-y_{n}|+\epsilon$. Passing to subsequences, we assume that $x_{n}\rightarrow x,y_{n}\rightarrow y$, $x,y\in X$ and taking limit to the inequality, a contradiction is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is bounded and uniformly continuous. Let $\delta >0$ be such that $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon$ for $|x-y|<\delta$. Let $C$ be an upper bound fro $|f|$ and take $M=\frac {2C} {\delta}$. Then $|f(x)-f(y)|  <\epsilon$ if $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq  2C \leq M|x-y|$ for $|x-y| \geq \delta$. Hence $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|+\epsilon$ for all $x,y$.